# PHP SwiftMailer from string to Message object

Tags: swiftmailer

As we know we can get email string from Swift Message object:

```
$message = new Swift_Message();
$message->setSubject("hi");
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('a.txt'));
$message->toString();
```

But can I parse mail string into Message object  ?
Great thanks!

Comment: What is a "mail string"?

Comment: Ah I think I understand. You want a `fromString`? Have you looked at serialize/deserialize?

Comment: serialize - it is not what I need. This Is sample of email string:

Comment: Message-ID: <be2dbaec2e394a1961de62a37b09d0e7@swift.generated>
Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 21:43:46 +0300
Subject: hi
From:
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="_=_swift_1530125026_43c3c1fd26b129de1a02015d4b803e9b_=_"


--_=_swift_1530125026_43c3c1fd26b129de1a02015d4b803e9b_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; name=a.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=a.txt

aGV5

--_=_swift_1530125026_43c3c1fd26b129de1a02015d4b803e9b_=_--

Comment: So like a parser... Not seeing anything in the docs. This thread is the most relevant thing I can find: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swiftmailer/2f3Pih07Ryg See the bit about what you describe being out of scope, "re-implementing SMTP" and suggestions to look at mailparse and mime-mail-parser.

Comment: It looks to me like swiftmailer is solely a library for constructing and sending messages, and thus includes serialization, but not parsing.  It looks like you would need a different library for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think php-mime-mail-parser can solve your problem:

> A fully tested email parser for PHP 7.1+ (mailparse extension wrapper).
>   It's the most effective php email parser around in terms of performance, foreign character encoding, attachment handling, and ease of use. Internet Message Format RFC 822, 2822, 5322.

https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser

Answer (score 0):

IT's not possible with Swift mail